# How to style a WordPress widget area?

Tags: css, wordpress

I registered a couple new widget areas above my content and below entries, and I'm having trouble styling them. The classes are `above_content` and `after_entry` but making an `.above_content` and `.after_entry` class in my stylesheet isn't affecting them. Any ideas? I'm just trying to align then and add padding. [My test site](http://gleefulthings.com/WPtestblog)

This is the code I used to register the widget area

```
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
    'id'          => 'after_entry',
    'name'        => __( 'After Entry', 'domain' ),
    'description' => __( 'After Entry', 'domain' ),
) );

add_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'your_widget2' );
function your_widget2() {
    if ( is_active_sidebar('after_entry') ) {
        genesis_widget_area( 'after_entry', array(
        'before' => '<div class=“after_entry widget-area">',
        'after'  => '</div>',
        ) ); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is wrong with your HTML,

```
<div class="“above_content" widget-area"="">
<div class="“after_entry" widget-area"="">
```

that's why class doesn't apply.

It should be like below,

```
<div class="above_content widget-area">
<div class="after_entry widget-area">
```

You had `“`, it should be `"`. check below,

```
genesis_register_sidebar( array(
    'id'          => 'after_entry',
    'name'        => __( 'After Entry', 'domain' ),
    'description' => __( 'After Entry', 'domain' ),
) );

add_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'your_widget2' );

function your_widget2() {
    if ( is_active_sidebar('after_entry') ) {
        genesis_widget_area( 'after_entry', array(
            'before' => '<div class="after_entry widget-area">',
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) ); 
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: hmmm I'm not sure how that would happen. Is there something wrong with the code I used to register the widget area? (added it above)

Comment: ahh! My text editor has been screwing those up for me when I copy and paste. Thank you SO much! Problem solved!

Comment: @Julie, Great enjoy.